# Bluez HID over GATT

Tags: linux, hid, bluez

Does bluez supports HID over GATT (HoG) as a client? i.e controlling an external device with mouse and keyboard requests.

I have failed to find any example code. I would be very grateful for any links to any examples which are available, or other such help.

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be similar to the BlueZ [GATT Server](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/test/example-gatt-server) example, except that the application will need to specifically expose HID over GATT (HoG) information. You will also need to advertise the service with the an [Advertisement](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/test/example-advertisement) specific to HoG.

Look at the HID over GATT Profile (HoGP) document at https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/

The XML detailing the service is available at: https://www.bluetooth.com/wp-content/uploads/Sitecore-Media-Library/Gatt/Xml/Services/org.bluetooth.service.human_interface_device.xml

The XML for each characteristic can be found by using the base URL of `https://www.bluetooth.com/wp-content/uploads/Sitecore-Media-Library/Gatt/Xml/Characteristics/<replace with characteristic type>.xml` and modifying it for the characteristic of interest from the service XML.
e.g. for `HID Information` the URL would be:
https://www.bluetooth.com/wp-content/uploads/Sitecore-Media-Library/Gatt/Xml/Characteristics/org.bluetooth.characteristic.hid_information.xml

If you want to search for more specific code examples in your preferred programming language then using terms like `BLE peripheral HID` might yield better results.